# Find the next number in the sequence?

Tags: number-sequence

1 = 1

2 = 12

3 = 27

4 = 44

5 = 35

6 = ?

The only hint I got was:

> “Think outside the box”

Comment: Hi MA8, welcome to PSE!  What is the source of the puzzle?

Comment: Hi Greg, I actually have no reliable source for the puzzle. My friend gave it to me and he’s a puzzle addict, and I have been trying to figure the answer since three days. I gave up so I thought I could get help here!

Comment: Gotcha.  No problem!  Hope you get your answer!

Comment: Could you perhaps list some of the possibilities or sequence rules you might have already tried?

Comment: I tried thinking of a mathematical formula for the sequence, none worked (I even used a computer to assist me). Then I came back to the hint and tried thinking about the words themselves: “one” “two” and so on, and I still can’t find a solution... But I am 90% sure it is not a mathematical sequence formula.

Comment: For me, the problem is your apex value is too close to the end of the pattern.  If you wanted a `box` analogy, the pattern would have been to have the 4 & 5 values be in decline, compared to the 2 & 3.  Value difference and division provide no insight

Comment: neither does digit multiplier evaluation.

Comment: Lastly....`27`, specifically `7` is the odd-ball in the pattern.  All other values can be easily deduced using standard patterns.

Comment: I know it sounds confusing, I can’t find a way to describe how I am thinking about it properly. But here is a puzzle that has a solution that is somehow similar to the way I am thinking about this puzzle: http://thescienceexplorer.com/universe/think-outside-box-find-next-number-sequence

Comment: think outside the box often implies that they are not base-ten numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> $6 = 816$

Reasoning

> I think they are all [Platonic numbers](http://oeis.org/wiki/Platonic_numbers) from a specific branch. 
>  1 = 1, the first Platonic number in all branches 
>  2 = 12, the second **icosahedral** number 
>  3 = 27, the third **cube** number 
>  4 = 44, the fourth **octahedral** number, 
>  5 = 35, the fifth **tetrahedral** number. 
>  Therefore, we must have 
>  6 = 816, the sixth **dodecahedral** number 
>  since this is the only remaining option.

Hint

> "Think outside the box" could refer to the idea of thinking about Platonic numbers beyond cubes.

Comment: The values start with basically (1)`Rank 4 -Dodecahedral` and go up to (5) `Rank 0 -Tetrahedral`

Comment: So it could be either `146` or `816` with `6` starting the cycle over again or just reflecting back down the Ranks

Comment: This is the most answer that makes sense until now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also...since all N forms have 1...it could be assumed that the sequence starts with `Dodecahedral` and goes up the `r` values...the only option after `5` is to either reflect or start all over from the "beginning